# Plugin for a cross browser content editable area

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, cross-browser, contenteditable

I am in need of a contenteditable plugin that will work well on all browsers + smartphones. I tried Codemirror but it was not working well on iphone. Then I tried [Editarea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/?page=editArea) and it works very well, but it is 150Kb, uses an iframe and has a lot of unnecessary code for me. What i need is a simple contenteditable area that will not allow the pasting of photos or other styled text and works well on phones as well.

Comment: absolutely no styling? maybe just use textarea then.

Comment: no i will inject some spans with javascript to put styling on only one thing that I want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to write your own handler since your logic is very custom. You'll have to disallow keyboard shortcuts like ctrl-b if you do not want to allow bolding for example. For paste, the best strategy to clean it is to inject a hidden div int o your contenteditable area  and then place the cursor in it to force the pasted content into it. At that point you can reference the div and clean out unwanted data e.g. images. Finall you can take the content and put it after the div and then remove the div.

Also consider pasting from Word which can be very messy. In the paste handling you can even make an ajax call with the data to clean it server side.